# Wireguard cloud server connection

Tags: wireguard, ubiquiti

I have a problem setting up connection with my cloud server, it kinda works but not as indended.

OK, so on my cloud server there is an internal network 192.168.33.0/24 in which all of VM's work. On one of them there is a wireguard server using `weejewel/wg-easy` docker image.

On my home network (192.168.22.0/24) I have a Edge router on which I've installed wireguard:

```
curl -OL https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-vyatta-ubnt/releases/download/1.0.20220627-1/e100-v2-v1.0.20220627-v1.0.20210914.deb
sudo dpkg -i e100-v2-v1.0.20220627-v1.0.20210914.deb
```

I provided it with following configuration:

```
configure
set interfaces wireguard wg0 address 10.8.0.2/24
set interfaces wireguard wg0 mtu 1420
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer *** allowed-ips 192.168.33.0/24
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer *** endpoint 'cloud.server.com:51820'
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer *** persistent-keepalive 25
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer *** preshared-key ***
set interfaces wireguard wg0 private-key ***
set interfaces wireguard wg0 route-allowed-ips true
commit
save
exit
```

Now, when I'm able to ping all of the hosts in cloud server network (192.168.33.0/24) from my router, but not from other hosts on the local network (192.168.22.0/24).

When I type `wg` I see that it's connected:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: ***
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 38942

peer: ***
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 54.36.174.46:51820
  allowed ips: 192.168.33.0/24
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 8 seconds ago
  transfer: 1.31 MiB received, 4.86 MiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

Routes also seam's to be fine:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 wg0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
default         static.tempus.n 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
172.16.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vtun0
***             0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth4
192.168.22.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.33.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I will check that and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: What is “it”? I wrote multiple things. Please be explicit. (You can also delete obsolete comments to keep this section clear.)

Comment: Sorry. I did not have much time yesterday. I've added following line.
```
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer *** allowed-ips 10.8.0.0/24
```
to configuration on my router.

On the clud side Wireguard is running in a docker environment so I have a bit limited options to modify it's configuration.

I wan't my home network to have access to the cloud network bot not the other way around.

Comment: Okay, I guess I was imprecise, too. Sorry about that. On the cloud server, when you run `wg`, does your edge router peer have in its allowed IPs _192.168.22.0/24_? On the cloud server, in the _192.168.33.0/24_ network, do you have a route to _192.168.22.0/24_ via your _wg-easy_ Docker container? So far, your question only has the “local” side covered.

Comment: Hi, I did not have much time lately, but now I'm back on this problem. So it seams that on the cloud side allowed ip's are not added:

    peer: ***
      preshared key: (hidden)
      endpoint: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
      allowed ips: 10.8.0.3/32
      latest handshake: 24 days, 20 hours, 39 minutes, 17 seconds ago
      transfer: 1.64 MiB received, 15.87 MiB sent

Comment: When I try to add 192.168.22.0/24 in allowedips in wg0.conf for my router pair it gets removed after start.

Comment: OK, so I've dropped this idea wg-easy is not suitable to be reused as a Site-to-Site like solution. I've just installed wireguard directly on proxmox and it works flawles

Comment: Great to hear you got it working as desired! Please add this information in an answer below. You can then accept your own answer after 48 hours, “officially” marking this question as solved.